# std::map::const_iterator template compilation error

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class that contains a `std::map` that stores pointers to T which refuses to compile:

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
public:
  // The following line won't compile
  std::map<int, T*>::const_iterator begin() const { return items.begin(); }

private:
  std::map<int, T*> items;
};
```

gcc gives me the following error:

```
error: type 'std::map<int, T*, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, T*> > >' is not derived from type 'Foo<T>'
```

Similarly, the following also refuses to compile:

`typedef std::map<int, T*>::const_iterator ItemIterator;`

However, using a map that doesn't contain the template type works OK, e.g.:

```
template <class T>
class Foo
{
public:
  // This is OK
  std::map<int, std::string>::const_iterator begin() const { return items.begin(); }

private:
  std::map<int, std::string> items;
};
```

I assume this is related to templates and begs the question - how can I return a `const_iterator` to my map?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `typename`:

```
typename std::map<int, T*>::const_iterator begin() const ...
```

When this is first passed by the compiler, it doesn't know what `T` is. Thus, it also doesn't know wether `const_iterator` is actually a type or not.

Such *dependent names* (dependent on a template parameter) are assumed to

- not be types unless prefixed by `typename`
- not to be templates unless directly prefixed by `template`.

Comment: +1 for completeness. Fortunately `template` does not creep in as often.

Comment: Ack! I tried typename but was putting it in the wrong place.  Thanks Georg.

Answer (score 2):

You need `typename`:

```
typename std::map<int, T*>::const_iterator begin() const { return items.begin(); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
typename std::map<int, T*>::const_iterator begin() const { return items.begin(); }
```

Or simpler

```
typedef typename std::map<int, T*>::const_iterator const_iterator;
const_iterator begin() const { return items.begin(); }
```

This is because `const_iterator` is dependent name on `T` so you need to tell compiler that it is actually type.